# Union and Left Join query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope someone can help me, I have two tables, of this tables I need one where i can have the sum of the hours use group by and where I can join them so I can make a comparation of the sum of those tables.

My idea it's a query like this but theres a error:

```
SELECT hagent.row_date, hagent.starttime_unix, SUM( hagent.i_stafftime ) 
FROM hagent
WHERE hagent.row_date = '2017-08-04'
AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('1700','1730','1800','1830','1900','1930','2000','2030','2100')
GROUP BY hagent.starttime_unix, hagent.row_date
UNION
SELECT hagent.row_date, hagent.starttime_unix, SUM( hagent.i_stafftime ) 
FROM hagent
WHERE hagent.row_date = '2017-08-05'
AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('900','930','1000','1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1300','1330','1400','1430','1500','1530','1600','1630')
GROUP BY hagent.starttime_unix, hagent.row_date
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime AS hora ,
    Sum(hsplit.i_stafftime)
    FROM
    hsplit
    WHERE
    hsplit.row_date = '2017-08-05'
    GROUP BY
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime
) s ON (hagent.starttime_unix = s.hora)
```

**NOTE**: Im not sure if the Join its correct

**EDITED**

This is the error code:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime,
    Sum(hsplit.i_staff' at line 12
```

Comment: Could you give us the error code ? Also provide the expected result if you know the result.

Comment: an example of what is in the table would be helpful too

Comment: You cannot have left join after a group by (unless that group by is part of an earlier subquery). [Official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) are pretty straightforward on what can go where.   ...making the UNIONed queries a subquery and joining to that should work.

Comment: @Noob Done, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things out of order.  Also, I think you can achieve this without the UNION because the only difference in your two queries is the WHERE.

```
SELECT hagent.row_date, hagent.starttime_unix, SUM( hagent.i_stafftime ) 
FROM hagent
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime AS hora ,
    Sum(hsplit.i_stafftime)
    FROM
    hsplit
    WHERE
    hsplit.row_date = '2017-08-05'
    GROUP BY
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime
) s ON (hagent.starttime_unix = s.hora)
WHERE (
    hagent.row_date = '2017-08-04'
    AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('1700','1730','1800','1830','1900','1930','2000','2030','2100')
    ) OR (
    hagent.row_date = '2017-08-05'
    AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('900','930','1000','1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1300','1330','1400','1430','1500','1530','1600','1630')
    )
GROUP BY hagent.starttime_unix, hagent.row_date
```

Let me know if that works. If you need the union for some specific reason:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT hagent.row_date, hagent.starttime_unix, SUM( hagent.i_stafftime ) 
    FROM hagent
    WHERE hagent.row_date = '2017-08-04'
    AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('1700','1730','1800','1830','1900','1930','2000','2030','2100')
    GROUP BY hagent.starttime_unix, hagent.row_date
    UNION
    SELECT hagent.row_date, hagent.starttime_unix, SUM( hagent.i_stafftime ) 
    FROM hagent
    WHERE hagent.row_date = '2017-08-05'
    AND hagent.starttime_unix IN('900','930','1000','1030','1100','1130','1200','1230','1300','1330','1400','1430','1500','1530','1600','1630')
) AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime AS hora ,
    Sum(hsplit.i_stafftime)
    FROM
    hsplit
    WHERE
    hsplit.row_date = '2017-08-05'
    GROUP BY
    hsplit.row_date,
    hsplit.starttime
) s ON (u.starttime_unix = s.hora)
GROUP u.starttime_unix, u.row_date
```

Sorry it's not formatted very well... I'm not on a computer with SQLMS where I can format it pretty.

Comment: HI! thanks for the answer, I think it works, but also I forget a very important thing, and it its that the times changes between the tables, one its on Spanish hour and the other its on Mexican hour, so the first show 3 columns but i think its for that Ill add more info. :)

Comment: @Urkidy Please ask another question relating to the issue of Mexican vs Spanish hour.  That's a completely different issue that someone else may be more capable to answer.